# Part of speech tagged as "word"

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using the [Stanford Part of Speech tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.html) on some Spanish text. As per their docs the part of speech tags come from this set: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/spanish-faq.shtml#tagset

Overall, I've found this to be accurate and haven't had an issue. However, I just ran into a small snippet of text: "Adiós ~ hailey". This is tagged as follows: `Adiós_i ~_word hailey_aq0000`. So the `~` symbol, which I think should get a punctuation tag of `f0` got a tag of `word`. That isn't documented or expected. Is this a bug or expected?

## Update

It turns out the special "word" tag appears in other contexts as well. I just saw it for the word `it` and the word `á`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! I've been a bit slow to catch up on documentation.. I just updated [the tag list in our documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/spanish-faq.shtml#tagset) to include the new `word`.

In the CoreNLP 3.7.0 release, we included new Spanish models trained on extra data (specifically, the DEFT Spanish Treebank V2). Some of the new data comes from a discussion forum dataset (Latin American Spanish Discussion Forum Treebank). This dataset uses an extra POS tag, `word`, to label emoticons and miscellaneous symbols (e.g. the ® sign).

(I know, it's a sort of silly choice of name — but we wanted to stick with what the original corpus used.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. That explains the `~`, but it seems odd that `it` got tagged with it. These are passages written by non native speakers so maybe they've just gotten the tagger confused??

Comment: I suppose if you turn your head and squint, it's sort of an emoticon. :)

Comment: More seriously: it could be a problem with the text you provided, but it's more likely due to the small amount of training data the tagger receives for this `word` tag. We didn't see a substantial performance drop when adding this tag, but if enough people report a problem, we might consider adding some sort of override.

Comment: One thought @Jon: with all the other tags you can differentiate the major "group" (noun, verb, punctuation, etc.) by just the first letter. But "word" has the same first letter as dates which adds one special case to code that otherwise can just do a map lookup based on first letter. Might be nice to change the tag to something that doesn't conflict.